# openCV rotate doesnt work with numpy array

Tags: python, numpy, opencv

I have a problem rotating my masked image in OpenCV 3.4.7. This code did work using OpenCV 4.1.0 but I can't use that version with docker so I'm stuck with 3.4. `masked` is an all-white image using the `eroded` dimensions times 255 to get an all-white OpenCV image that I need for masking specific part on the `eroded` image.

When rotating my `mask` like this i get errors.

```py
masked = np.ones(eroded.shape, dtype=np.uint8) * 255
mask = np.asarray(masked)
mask = cv2.rotate(mask, cv2.ROTATE_90_CLOCKWISE)
```

The error:

> cv2.error: OpenCV(3.4.7) C:\projects\opencv-python\opencv\modules\core\src\copy.cpp:811: error: (-215:Assertion failed) _src.dims() <= 2 in function 'cv::rotate'

Comment: It could be you have some problems with the eroded object, everything else seems to be fine.

Comment: @YaroslavKornachevskyi The eroded image is just an imported image so there is nothing wrong with that. the problem is also that masked is an array but mask is a tuple for some reason

Comment: Can you post full source ? Image is a grayscale one ? Also, can you print masked and mask ?

Comment: no i cant post full source. yes the image is grayscale with a threshold.

Comment: Ok, I have tried the following: img = cv2.imread('test.png')
_, img = cv2.threshold(cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY), 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
masked = np.ones(img.shape, dtype=np.uint8) * 255
ar = np.asarray(masked)
mask = cv2.rotate(ar, cv2.ROTATE_90_CLOCKWISE)
And I have no errors at all. That's why I am thinking of some problems with the  eroded object.

Comment: Removing the `np.asarray()` worked for me. When `masked` is created using `np.ones()`, the object type is `<class 'numpy.ndarray'>` so there's no need to convert it into a Numpy array with `np.asarray()`. Maybe your `eroded` image is invalid or Nonetype?